# Add costum module in vtiger project sidebar

Tags: php, module, sidebar, vtiger

I've created a custom sample module (a simple Hello world) and now I would add a link to this module in projects on vtiger.
I've tried to use the module designer but it didn't work, so I've found this piece of code in module.php file in vtiger/modules/project/models/

```
public function getSideBarLinks($linkParams) {
    $linkTypes = array('SIDEBARLINK', 'SIDEBARWIDGET');
    $links = parent::getSideBarLinks($linkParams);

    $quickLinks = array(
        array(
            'linktype' => 'SIDEBARLINK',
            'linklabel' => 'LBL_TASKS_LIST',
            'linkurl' => $this->getTasksListUrl(),
            'linkicon' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'linktype' => 'SIDEBARLINK',
            'linklabel' => 'LBL_MILESTONES_LIST',
            'linkurl' => $this->getMilestonesListUrl(),
            'linkicon' => '',
        ),
    );
    foreach($quickLinks as $quickLink) {
        $links['SIDEBARLINK'][] = Vtiger_Link_Model::getInstanceFromValues($quickLink);
    }

    return $links;
}
```

But even if I add here my custom link or if I delete all the content in $quickLinks array the sidebar doesn't change. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer below link or follow below steps to add new link under project module.

[Add new custom link](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/vtlib/module-related-list.html)

Create a new file and add below code in that .PHP file and place it at CRM root directory location and run in browser.

```
$Crm_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Crm/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Crm/Module.php');

$module = Crm_Module::getInstance('Project');
$targetmodule = Crm_Module::getInstance('NewModule');
$relationLabel = 'Link Label';
$function_name = 'get_related_list';
$module->setRelatedList( $targetmodule, $relationLabel, Array(), $function_name );
```